# NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification while app is closed

Tags: ios, ios4, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

An app I'm working on stores the user's info for syncing with a webservice in the settings bundle.  I was able to successfully detect a change using the NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification notification but only while the app was in the background.  If I fully closed the app and launched again it doesn't get that notification.  I know the system coalesces notifications for an app while it's in the background but is there any way to receive when the app launches initially?  If not is there a good workaround?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user defaults only change in the context of the application.

Nothing changes after you close it, and there's nothing to notify you about when it relaunches.

Read the values you need on launch.

Comment: Yup that's what I figured, I'll store the current username in the app and compare on when syncing to determine if they changed username, thanks.

Comment: Your user defaults can also change outside the context of the app if you have an MDM profile installed and the app is managed (see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/3-MDM_Protocol/MDM_Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017387-CH3-SW68). NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification should execute when app opens (see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html).